# SocketLabs integration for Drupal 7?

Tags: civimail, drupal, integration, drupal-6

Are there any current integrations with SocketLabs that would report failed sends, hard bounces and spam reports back to CiviCRM in a Drupal 7 site?

There is a 5 year old integration between SocketLabs and CiviCRM running in Drupal 6 to get the failures and spam emails: https://github.com/emotive/CiviCRM-socketlabs-integration. It uses the Reporting API to periodically on cron runs gather problem email send information from SocketLabs. Their currently recommended approach is to use their Notification API to get a callback immediately on each problematic outbound email.

Of course, one can use SocketLabs for outbound email without having a method to get the bounces, fails, and spam notifications. This ends up creating a suppression list in SocketLabs that is great for protecting the reputation of the email sending organization, but with the following significant downsides:

1. Inaccurate reporting in CiviCRM of deliveries and spam.
2. Wasted costs to the organization using CiviCRM money for emails sent that get suppressed,
3. Potentially harms the organization's email reputation if they send transactional emails to these addresses.

Once again: anyone know of other integrations or efforts to create one?